# The acceleration of universal expansion in terms of volume

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, dark-energy

I've been trying to work out a formula for the second time-derivative of volume in a dark-energy dominated universe, in terms of the radius. But I'm not sure my intuition is correct.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_universe, $a(t) = e^{Ht}$ where $H \approx  2.2*10^{-18}s^{-1}$.

I figured we could consider the scale factor $a(t)$ as the radius $r(t)$ if we multiply it by some reference with units of length, say 1 meter. So

$r(0) = e^{Ht}m$

Then

$V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 = \frac{4}{3} \pi e^{3Ht} m^3$

$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{4}{3} \pi 3H e^{3ht} m^3 = 4 \pi H e^{3Ht} m^3$

$\frac{d^2V}{dt^2} = 4 \pi H*3H e^{3Ht} m^3= 12 \pi H^2 e^{3Ht} m^3$

The units for this would be $m^3s^{-2}$, which makes sense as in "new volume per second per second."

I don't know exactly how to interpret this. Can I use this formula to calculate $\Delta V$ for any initial volume? That is ultimately what I want, to be able to say how much a given volume of space accelerates in its expansion based on a bunch of constants. I'm not really interested in the theoretical background, as I figured we can just consider the measured recession velocities and derive a simplified, non-relativistic model from there.